# How to add JQuery in CQWP web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, content-query-web-part

I have created custom CQWP web part in which i am sliding news contents. I have created structure for sliding contents. Now i want to add JQuery file reference in my CQWP web part but it gives error while adding reference in Mainfile of CQWP.

I have tried this code but it gives error..

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('<script src=&quot;/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js&quot;></script>')"/>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('<script src=&quot;/SiteAssets/jssor.js&quot;></script>')"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help to how to add external script reference in CQWP web part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following snippet can be used to reference the jQuery in your XSLT webpart.

**Inline Script Block:**

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> 
    <![CDATA[ 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            (your JavaScript code here) 
        </script> 
    ]]> 
</xsl:text>
```

**Script Reference Block:**

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> 
    <![CDATA[ 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
    ]]> 
</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Thanks @Predip.. It works like a charm...!!
Thank you so much..!!